# print scapy sniff output to file

Tags: python, scapy

I have created a sniffer in scapy and I want the packets captured by scapy to be written onto a file for further analysis?

```
def sniffer(ip):
    filter_str = "icmp and host " + ip
    packets=sniff(filter=filter_str,count=20)
    f = open('log.txt',"a")
    #f.write(packets)
```

The last line of code does not work. Is there any way I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f.write` expects a character buffer, but you supply it with a `Sniffed` object which is the result of calling `sniff`. You can, very simply, do the following:

```
f.write(str(packets))
```

This should work. But it probably won't display the information exactly as you would like it. You are going to have to do more work collecting information from `packets` as strings before you write to `f`.